# QT is there a way to delay signal and/or abandon signal?

Tags: c++, qt

I am looking for a way to delay or abandon signal under some circumstances.

My GUI looks like that - I have a MainWindow frame, which contains QStackedWidget with several QWidgets. Each QWidget 'provides' `mainIcon` to the parent widget (MainWindow), which is then connected to a slot realizing switching between pages functionality.

I want to connect this `mainIcon` to a signal, show a QMessageBox and if user confirms - everything will happen normally (a signal will be passed and analyzed by parent Widget) - after a delay(user has to confirm).

However, if he declines, a signal should not be passed, and nothing should happen.

What I have came up with so far is:

```
connect(mainIcon, &GuiIconAction::clicked, this, [=](){
        //block signals of mainIcon - should be somehow ensured that this is the first realized slot
        if(confirmRequired)
        {
            if(QMessageBox::warning(this, "Manager",
                                    "Are you sure you want to switch window?",
                                    QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No) == QMessageBox::No)
                return;
        //get blocked signals and call them
        }
    });
```

Important notes are:

- `GuiIconAction` is a QToolButton,
- `Widget` don't know that the parent exists (i.e. it just provides interface, but could also be placed standalone)
- I don't want to realize this functionality in parent widget (MainWindow), as it is only a frame - I want it to be realized on the level of particular Widget in QStackedWidget

Comment: whenever you want to create delay, you should use a `single shot`. but I didn't understand what you really want.

Comment: "I don't want to realize this functionality in parent widget" - it feels like the wheels deciding where the car goes. Which signals do you want to block? The QMessageBox is modal, so nothing should happen. You could of course call QObject::blockSignals() on whatever you want, but needing this feels like the car going where the wheels want...

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to implement the functionality with a slot.
In the slot you can create the message box. If the user confirms, emit a signal. Otherwise not.

Comment: yeah, it seems that delay word is not the correct word about what he wants.